# What is a word that means "mental" but applies more to this sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

He believed in mental freedom from religious organizations.

I am trying to say that he believed in forming your own thoughts, without religious organizations telling you what to think. If you wanted to be part of the religious organization, then it was because you formed your own thoughts and then decided to join.

Of course I did not say everything in that single sentence, because it is currently a work in progress. I am just looking for the right word.

Comment: One common phrasing would be "psychic autonomy" in place of "mental freedom".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**freedom of conscience**

> The right to follow one’s own beliefs in matters of religion and
>   morality. -[OED](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/freedom-of-conscience)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps he believed in freedom of thought without intrusion from others, especially representatives of organizations wishing you to join, such as religious groups.